# User added text to annotation [XCode]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a beginner with XCode and I am trying to find a way for the User to input information inside a callbox of a pin they had placed on the map.

So if the User drops a pin and they tap on the pin, I want them to be able to type in a title and a subtitle of that location.

So far, I have created a map using MKMapView and I have implemented UILongPressGestureRecognizer and a void method that fires the moment a pin is created.

I am not sure what to do next? Thank you for your help.

Edit1: I don't have the required reputation to post an image, so here is a link of what I am trying to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSV6r.jpg

If it is possible to type in the title and subtitle without the use of a disclosure button, that would be swell. Later on I will develop the disclosure button.

Edit2: I have three new questions: 1. Why isn't my disclosure button appearing in my callout? 2. What is reuseidentifier for? Here is what I have so far.

I have embedded a navigation controller to my initial view controller that has the MKMapView in it. I created a second View Controller and I connected the MKMapView to the second View Controller and made my identifier for the second View Controller as 'heylisten' (good old Zelda).

My third question is in the prepareForSegue method, what information needs to go after the dot? destinationViewController.???? = sender.annotation;

```
// This is your callout box
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"overhere"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIButton *rightDisclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightDisclosureButton;


    return annotationView;
}

// This is a segue when you tap the right disclosure button
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"heylisten" sender:view];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(MKAnnotationView *)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"heylisten"])
    {
        ViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        // grab the annotation from the sender

        destinationViewController = sender.annotation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting iOS 8, use a UIAlertController:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/

If you're targeting iOS 7 or earlier, use a UIAlertView:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertView

Both of these types have mechanisms to add an input text field and specify a callback to be executed with the text the user typed.

Comment: I updated my answer, I don't think a pop up alert view is the right choice.

Comment: That thing coming out of the pin is a callout. There's documentation for them and basically it's limited to having an accessory on the left, a title, subtitle and detail disclosure button. You could use a popover on the iPad which is what UIAlertController and UIAlertView would give you, you could push another view controller to enter details, or you could somehow place another view containing what you want on top of the appropriate spot on the map.

Comment: Sweet, thank you. I am going to go with pushing a segue, because I am working on an iPhone at the moment. I will do UIAlertController/View once I head over to the iPad. I updated my information; if you could take a moment to glance at it. Thank you.